# How can data come in my network if incoming ports are closed?

Tags: tcp, port

On my home network router all incoming ports are closed.
How is it possible for data to come in my home network? For instance, when I make an HTTP Request, which incoming ports are the HTTP response packets using to come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Incoming ports closed" means that no connection attempts are accepted from the outside. If connections are initiated from the inside then a connection state is maintained and if incoming packets match this state they are allowed through.

Comment: I can't understand which ports incoming packets are using.

Comment: @Nicola: A connection for HTTP is using a random source port on the local system (I take 54321 as example here) and connect to a specific port on the server (like 443 for HTTPS). A state will be created which will allow response packets back, i.e. packets originating in port 443 at the server and targeting port 54321 at the local system. That's the basic idea at least. With TCP more things than just the port number are part of the state, specifically the sequence numbers.

Comment: Thank you, I got it!